# Firebase Analytics time filter and timezone

Tags: firebase-analytics

What timezone is used in Firebase Analytics Dashboard filter? 
I expect than it is UTC timezone, but no proof found anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Analytics uses the timezone associated with the developer who created the Firebase Project in its reporting by default.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the path where you can check and change TimeZone.
Go to Project Settings -> Integrations -> Click on Google Analytics

[image]